# List::iterator value not correct

Tags: c++, iterator

So I have ListOne and ListTwo and both are containing {9, 11, 12}.However, in the code below, my iterators holding the values of the end of the lists hold a value that is not even in the list.
EDIT: So I found out that listOne.end() is returning the size of the list. Why?

```
auto firstIteratorBegin = listOne.begin();
auto secondIteratorBegin = listTwo.begin();
auto firstIteratorEnd = listOne.end();
auto secondIteratorEnd = listTwo.end();

//Check if two lists are in the same range.
if(*firstIteratorEnd < *secondIteratorBegin || *secondIteratorEnd < *firstIteratorBegin)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What type are your list variables?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

`end()` will return an iterator to the position one *past the last element* of the container, so dereferencing it is undefined.

Assuming you already checked that the lists are not empty and are bi-directional, you can get the iterator to the last element by decremented your end iterator once. Alternatively you could use `rbegin`, but that is a different iterator type.

If you simply want the values, many containers will have `front()` and `back()` members that directly return a reference to the value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `listOne` is a container from the Standard Library, `listOne.end()` gives you an iterator to **past-the-end** of the container.

Dereferencing such iterator is **undefined behavior**.